# How to target Local Path on TrainCustomModelAsync Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

Can someone explain to me how TrainModelAsync can access local path on windows as the Source files.
The documentation said:

> The request must include a source parameter that is either an externally accessible Azure storage blob container Uri (preferably a Shared Access Signature Uri) or valid path to a data folder in a locally mounted drive. **When local paths are specified, they must follow the Linux/Unix path format and be an absolute path rooted to the input mount configuration setting value e.g., if '' configuration setting value is '/input' then a valid source path would be '/input/contosodataset'.** All data to be trained is expected to be under the source folder or sub folders under it. Models are trained using documents that are of the following content type - 'application/pdf', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/tiff'. Other type of content is ignored.

1. What is the valid format for example i have the train files in C:\input\ ?
2. What is input mount configuration setting value?

Here is my code: (This run successfully if I set the "Source" property to a blob storage)

```
  var client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = "https://MYRESOURCENAME.cognitiveservices.azure.com/formrecognizer/v2.0-preview/custom/models/";
        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", ENDPOINT_KEY);

        var body =
            new
            {
                source = new Uri("C:\\train\\").AbsolutePath,
                sourceFilter = new
                {
                    prefix = "",
                    includeSubFolders = false
                },
                useLabelFile = true
            };


        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local path option only applies when you run the Form Recognizer service as a container in your own Docker/Kubernetes environment. The hosted Form Recognizer service can only read training data from an Azure Blob Container URL.

That said, local containers are currently only available for the older v1.0-preview. You can read more about v1.0-preview container at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/form-recognizer-container-howto

Comment: Currently form recognizer labeling tool comes as a windows installer also. Can we set local file path as Source attribute there. If yes how the path should look like.